# Google Sheets Query Function - Where column not equal to a specific range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Got a query running in google sheets that is filtering a large range of data down into a short list with items in a specific order.

```
=Query('2022'!$B2:$O,"Select H,B,E,O where M = date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE($N$1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' And (H Contains '"&P1&"' or H Contains '"&P2&"' or H Contains '"&P3&"' or H Contains '"&P4&"') Order by O asc",0)
```

I'm trying to add another "where" condition

`And B != '"&A2:A30&"'`

But adding this condition doesn't work.
Am I missing something obvious or is this not possible?
I can get it to work by typing a single value in the query, but it wont work with a cell reference or a range of cell references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with "matches" condition and TEXTJOIN:

```
   ..."AND not B matches '\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b",1,A2:A30)&"\b' ...."
```

Comment: Thanks Martin - that works :-)
I would ask why but right now - it's working so I will finish what I'm doing! - many thanks

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! "matches" allows you to use [regular expressions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=en) - then with TEXTJOIN you can concatenate all the values with the corresponding delimiters `\b` implies beginning of a word and `|` is "or" - other way without regular expressions with be to use TEXTJOIN with the phrase `OR not B = ` for examplee